# Strapi POST API for content-type with relational fields

Tags: javascript, relationship, strapi

Every time I try to create an order via /api/orders it gives me 400 (Bad request), there doesn't seem to be a proper clear explanation anywhere on how to create records with relational fields, the only one I found close to what I needed was this: [image: Strapi "Create an entry" docs with relational fields]

So supposedly I should use an id or a list of ids depending on the type of relation, but it still gives me 400 Bad request with no explanation in the response.

My order content-type looks like this:

[image: Order content-type]

User is a Many-to-One relationship, so a user can have many orders, but there can only be one user per order, and products is One-to-Many, so an order can have many products

This is what my API call looks like:

```js
    await axios.post(
      `${baseUrl}/api/orders`,
      {
        products: [9],
        total: 320,
        user: 42
      }
    );
```

The products and user ids are exactly the ones I have in the database and authentication is not the problem.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I should be creating records with relational fields.

Comment: Can you share the data you are sending to the /api/order route?

Comment: Never mind, I've seen it. In your question you referenced /api/order while in your example code you reference /api/orders is that correct?

Comment: @nasirmustapha yeah it is supposed to be /api/orders, that's the route shown in users permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, apparently it does give me a proper response describing the problem, it's just I had to go to the Network tab in the browser and find it there, and it's the stupidest thing, all I had to do it is this:

```js
    await axios.post(
      `${baseUrl}/api/orders`,
      {
        data: {
          products: [9],
          total: 320,
          user: 42
        }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from your route, accessing it with ${baseurl}/orders should work fine.

Comment: This is not the answer, every other api route has the /api prefix, why wouldn't this one? I am sure the problem is somewhere in the data I'm passing but I can't seem to find a way to structure it

Answer (score 0):

In the case you cannot update a reference even with the right JSON structure like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71276897/2735286), then check the permissions given to the referenced entity.

Check that the update and create permissions are granted like here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had similair problem and
enabling find user under USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN worked for me.